# Unwanted numbers added to a url in a bibitem

Tags: bibliographies, urls

I face a weird problem. I use `\url{}` (URL package) to specify a URL in a `bibitem`. After compiling my LateX file, the URL is well displayed in my PDF file. But, when I drag the mouse over the URL, the URL that is displayed in the floating box appearing is wrong: it contains additional numbers. When I click on it, my browser goes to this wrong URL and does not find of course any website. My URL is quite long and it seems that these unwanted numbers appear whenever a linebreak is used by LateX.

Could anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. A suggestion: Change your username to something more friendly than "user21071". Also, it would probably be easier for people to help you if you could include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem

Answer (score 2):

If your PDF viewer has made the link using some heuristics, then try package `hyperref` to get link annotations in the PDF file. Otherwise a MWE would show problematic characters in the URL (they might need to be percent encoded).

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, but what do you mean by MWE ?

Comment: Moreover, when using hyperref with long URLs, it doesn't break properly the URLs

Comment: OK I got it. Here is a MWE:

Comment: \url{http://archive.defra.gov.uk/environment/quality/noise/research/documents/human-response-vibration-residential-environments.pdf} is what I type in my LateX file. http://archive.defra.1181gov.uk/environment/quality/noise/research/1182documents/human-response-vibration-residential-environments.1183pdf is the URL address my browser is looking for.

Comment: @Arnaud See the first comment of Corentin to your question. It contains a link that explains "MWE". When using `hyperref` use a driver that supports broken links or in some cases package `breakurl` helps, see `README` of `hyperref`.